# Encrypting/decrypting cookies in .NET 2.0 (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

would please someone guide me how to encrypt and decrypt cookies in Asp.net 2.0, any reference would be great

thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

1. [HttpSecureCookie, A Way to Encrypt Cookies with ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/HttpSecureCookie.aspx)
2. [Encrypting Cookie Data with ASP.NET](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/021210.htm)

Comment: Warning from 4.5 years in the future about method #1: Microsoft has now deprecated the System.Web.Security.CookieProtectionHelper class. So while reflecting into that internal class will work as long as you are in 2.0, it will stop working in 4.5. In .Net 4.0 the System.Web.Security.MachineKey class was introduced with a public Encode and Decode class that works the same way (although Protect and Unprotect are recommended). Once .Net 4.5.1 is installed, you will find that it is no longer possible to call the CookieProtectionHelper class, even though you may still also have .Net 2.0 installed.